# A parametric version of Hurwitz' theorem (of complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Hurwitz' theorem says the following. Say $(f_n)$ is a sequence of a holomorphic functions (on a domain $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{C}$) converging uniformly on compact subsets to a non-constant holomorphic function $f$. Then, if $f$ has a zero at $z \in \Omega$, for $\rho<0$ sufficiently small, and $K \in \mathbb{N}$ sufficiently large, each $f_n, n \geq k,$ will have a zero in the disc $D(z, \rho)$...moreover these zeros converge to $z$ as $k \to \infty$.

In rough terms, Hurwitz' theorem says that if we perturb a holomorphic function slightly, we only move the zeros slightly.

Does anyone know if the following is true (and if so, may I be directed to a proof of the same?): if $F: [0,1] \times \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous family of holomorphic functions (i.e., $F(t, \cdot)$ is holomorphic), and, for some $s \in [0,1]$, $F(s, \cdot)$ has a zero at $\zeta_s$, then there is a neighbourhood of $V \subset [0,1]$ of $s$ with a continuous function $V \to \Omega, t \mapsto \zeta_t,$ such that $F(t, \zeta_t)=0$?

It seems like it must be true!

Comment: how can you prove this using the open mapping theorem >:)

Comment: Does it not follow from the implicit function theorem (with the assumption let's say that $\frac{d}{dz}F(t, \zeta_t)\neq 0$)?

Comment: Does the standard proof using Hurwitz that roots of analytic functions over $\mathbb C^n (n \ge 2)$ cannot be isolated be modified to work for this?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! I'm quite interested in the assertion by @WhoKnowsWho as I too have been thinking along the lines of the implicit function theorem with that assumption...but I haven't been able to get a working proof! Would it be possible to elaborate?